# onCloseDialog event not working in my Controller. What's wrong with my code?

Tags: sapui5

I'm trying to learn SAPUI5 and following the walkthrough in SAPUI5 documentation. I'm currently in Step 17: Fragment Callbacks. I am not able to make the onCloseDialog event work. The code I double and triple checked and I could not find anything wrong. There is also no error in Chrome's console. Any insights?

Link to the guide I'm following:

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/354f98ed2b514ba9960556333428d35e

My code for:

HelloDialog.fragment.xml

```
<core:FragmentDefinition xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core">
<Dialog id="helloDialog" title="Hello {/recipient/name}">
    <content>
        <core:Icon src="sap-icon://hello-world" size="8rem" class="sapUiMediumMargin"/>
    </content>
    <beginButton>
        <Button text="{i18n>dialogCloseButtonText}" press="onCloseDialog"/>
    </beginButton>
</Dialog>
```

My code for:
HelloPanel.controller.js

```
sap.ui.define([
"sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
"sap/m/MessageToast"
], function(Controller, MessageToast) {
"use strict";
return Controller.extend("sap.ui.demo.wt.controller.HelloPanel", {
    onShowHello: function() {
        // read msg from i18n model
        var oBundle = this.getView().getModel("i18n").getResourceBundle();
        var sRecipient = this.getView().getModel().getProperty("/recipient/name");
        var sMsg = oBundle.getText("helloMsg", [sRecipient]);
        // show message
        MessageToast.show(sMsg);
    },
    onOpenDialog: function() {
        var oView = this.getView();
        var oDialog = oView.byId("helloDialog");
        // create dialog lazily
        if (!oDialog) {
            // create dialog via fragment factory
            oDialog = sap.ui.xmlfragment(oView.getId(), "sap.ui.demo.wt.view.HelloDialog");
            oView.addDependent(oDialog);
        }


        oDialog.open();
    },
    onCloseDialog: function() {
        this.getView().byId("helloDialog").close();
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed to pass the controller reference when creating the dialog from the fragment.
In case of the Walkthrough step, it's the same controller object as the dialog caller, so `this` should be passed:

<strike>`sap.ui.xmlfragment(oView.getId(), "sap.ui.demo.wt.view.HelloDialog", this);`</strike><sup>⚠️</sup>

API reference: <strike>[`sap.ui.xmlfragment`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui#methods/sap.ui.xmlfragment)</strike><sup>⚠️</sup>

---

#### ⚠️ `sap.ui.*fragment` is **deprecated**!

- Instead, use one of the APIs mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/64541325/5846045.
- Documentation topic: [Instantiation of Fragments](https://sdk.openui5.org/topic/04129b2798c447368f4c8922c3c33cd7)